# Why conda list does not show packages

Tags: conda

I'm using

```
~ $ conda --version
conda 4.0.5
```

Which has some stuff installed in

```
~ $ conda list | head -3
# packages in environment at /glade/apps/contrib/anaconda2:
#
alabaster                 0.7.7                    py27_0
```

But it looks like it does not have tensorflow

```
~ $ conda list | grep tensorflow
~ $
```

Now, the odd thing is that tensorflow is there:

```
~ $ ls -l /glade/apps/contrib/anaconda2/pkgs/tensor* -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csgteam csgteam 26253041 Oct 26 15:44 /glade/apps/contrib/anaconda2/pkgs/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-np111py27_0.tar.bz2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csgteam csgteam 33132127 Oct 26 15:28 /glade/apps/contrib/anaconda2/pkgs/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py27_0.tar.bz2

/glade/apps/contrib/anaconda2/pkgs/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-np111py27_0:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 csgteam csgteam 4096 Oct 26 15:44 bin
drwxrwxr-x 3 csgteam csgteam 4096 Oct 26 15:44 info
drwxrwxr-x 3 csgteam csgteam 4096 Oct 26 15:44 lib

/glade/apps/contrib/anaconda2/pkgs/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py27_0:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 2 csgteam csgteam 4096 Oct 26 15:28 bin
drwxrwxr-x 3 csgteam csgteam 4096 Oct 26 15:28 info
drwxrwxr-x 3 csgteam csgteam 4096 Oct 26 15:28 lib
```

Why conda list does not show it, or better, what should I do to make it appear in the list? Note that it ended up in that cache when I first installed with `conda install` (which downloaded it).

If I try to install version 0.10, it does install from the cache, whereas if I want to install version 0.11, I have to specify the conda-forge channel (and then installs from the cache too). Why?

Comment: Apparently, `tensorflow` is not installed in your environment. This is why it doesn't show up in `conda list`. However, you apparently installed it at some point in the past, so `conda` cached the tarball and the extracted directory for `0.10` and `0.11`. I'm not sure what your question is then, this seems to be the expected behavior. Are you expecting it to be installed in the environment? If it were installed, it would also be listed in the `site-packages` directory. Did you `conda install tensorflow` again?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm trying to set up this environment (namely `/glade/apps/contrib/anaconda2`) as a root-owned read-only cache for users to use, because on this large machine we do **not** want every user to download and install the same package, for space and security reasons. Still, how can you say that it's the expected behavior when the file/directories are there but not shown in conda list?

Comment: Oh, I misread the search you were listing. Is there a `tensorflow` folder in your `site-packages` directory? If there isn't, then the package isn't properly installed for one reason or another...